# How to get all new code between commits and save them to folder

Tags: git

Due to legal issues I need to get all new code files between two distant commits (2 years of development). I need only whole new files, changes in existed files are not required. I am using Fork and I can see all new files, but I need all of them extracted to folder and I don't know how to do it. How to do it with git commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all files that are new in `commitB` with respect to `commitA` :

```
git diff --name-only --no-renames --diff-filter=A <commitA> <commitB>
```

To make a tar archive out of those :

```
# the active commit must be commitB,
# 'git status' must indicate a clean worktree (no changes to any versioned files)

git diff --name-only ... | xargs tar -cf newfiles.tar

# if you want it gzipped :
git diff --name-only ... | xargs tar -czf newfiles.tgz
```

Comment: This is nearly what i want, but not exactly. This command gives all files that was added any time between A and B, even if it was deleted afterwards (before B).

Comment: You mention "legal issues" : would that legal stuff be waived off if a file was deleted then re-added ?

Comment: If you are looking for "all files that have been added or modified between A and B": that's `--diff-filter=AM`

Comment: if you want to see what files have been deleted at some point in the history between `A` and `B` : `git log --oneline --name-only --no-renames --diff-filter=D A..B` and scan through that

Comment: I want to see files that was added, but not deleted. If file was Created at commit C and Deleted at commit D, and commit order was A C D B - I don't want to see this file. If file was deleted and then readded - this is what i don't want to see either (but i think it is hard to find, because same file can be added with different name, then modified and stuff, so this is not strictly required).

Comment: Looks like I did something wrong yesterday. I used that command again today and it work as required... So accepting answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/questions/117626/find-recently-added-files-with-git

Other way I can think of, without any git magic:

Checkout commit A, copy your project to some folder. Checkout commit B.

Now find the files that exist in B, but not in A. These files have been added since A.

Answer (score 0):

Do a soft git reset to the earliest commit using `git reset HEAD~<number of commits to go back>`

This will reset all the changes and bring the codebase to the earliest commit. You shoudl be able to see all changes including modifications to existing files and new files.

Now do a `git checkout .` and that will remove all changes to the files that existed at that commit and the later commits. You will be left only with files that did not exist at the earliest commit.

Additionally if you want to remove those new files also, you will have to do a `git clean -f .`.